# Hide/Show div, how to change tag within script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show

I have a fairly simple working script which shows and hides a div.

The problem is that I cannot set the tag to an ID or class and currently it is set to an element selector which is not what I want. What can I change within this JS will allow me to set it to a class I can show/hide on click. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dXWAY/2/

```
$("p").click(function () {
    $("div").slideToggle("slow");
})

p {

    border:0 none;

    font-size:2em;

    background:transparent;

}

div {

    display:none;

    width:400px;

    height:200px;

    background:#f5f5f5;

}

<p>hello</p>
<div class="div">hello</div>
```

Comment: You can't ever click the `p` because of `display: none` on `div`

Comment: What do you want to do. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Were you trying to create an accordion?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXWAY/6/)**

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-img">
        <a class="toggleBtn">Click Me!</a>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore accusamus porro modi ut itaque ipsum natus explicabo vero sequi beatae libero voluptatibus sit culpa debitis tempore! Sint eum ipsum consequatur!</div>
    </div>
</div>

#portfolio {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-img {
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;  
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    clear:left;    
}

.toggleBtn {
    background:deepskyblue;
    display:block;
    float:Left;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.content {
    background:skyblue; 
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

$('.content').hide();

$('.toggleBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean that ???

```
$("#myP").click(function () {
    $("#myDiv").slideToggle("slow");
})

<p id="myP">hello</p>
<div class="myDiv">hello</div>
```

Comment: Yes, except I set it to a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change div to .div or better yet, be less confusing and make it more human readable:

```
.hideableDiv {

display:none;

width:400px;

height:200px;

background:#f5f5f5;

}
```

Where **.** is specifying this is the name of a class.

In essence your

```
<div class="div">
```

Is not applying a class because "div" in your css meant apply this to all div elements.

With the modifications I suggest your div would become

```
<div class="hideableDiv">
```

This would then make your jQuery selector:

```
$(".hideableDiv")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. itried setting classes/id earlier, but couldn't get it to work and I think it's because I didn't add the "." to the selector within JS I got it working with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dXWAY/5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but looking at your fiddle, the p can't be in a div since your css sets all divs to display:none.

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-img">

        <div class="div">hello</div>>
    </div>
</div>

<p>hello</p>
```

As subterfuge mentioned, it would be better to assign your display:none to a class rather than all div elements.

See here

http://jsfiddle.net/jboneca/dXWAY/4/